# How can I merge two identical commits with different hash?

Tags: git, merge, duplicates, patch

I have access to a contractor’s Git repo with read-only permissions. I pull his branches (`smile/dev` -> `dev`) from his server and then push them back on my GitLab server. I then do my modifications on a custom branch (`sectronic` -> `origin/sectronic`), and can then rebase or merge their `smile/dev` into my `sectronic` branch if some changes happen on their side.

Now recently I commited a bugfix to my `sectronic` branch, from which I exported a patch that I sent to my contractor. He applied the patch on his `smile/dev` branch, so now I have two different commits in my tree but both doing the same changes (the two top ones).

[image: Commit tree]

How can I get out of this situation? I cannot delete my branch because I have past modifications that I want to keep, I can’t really hard revert to my own commit because I could have done other commits after this one. I’m not currently skilled enough in Git to know how to clean this up properly.

I know the workflow is suboptimal and a proper way of making this work is through the use of pull/merge requests, but that’s sadly not currently possible in my situation.

Comment: if the modification is almost the same, merging the two shall produce a minimum number of merge conflicts. If you'd like to keep the history clean and track this, ask your client to make a revert commit on their side (or do it on your side) removing the duplicate bugfix _with a new commit_.

Comment: You can interactive rebase to drop the commit from your branch. However, it isn’t clear that the current situation is bad; it’s no different from a cherry pick. Why not just leave it as it is?

Comment: @DaemonPainter In that case they would lose the patch commit, as they won’t include my commit directly. It is a weird workflow where I commit normaly on my side, but they only apply patches of my changes and commit them on their branch, that I then pull…

Comment: @matt Thanks, dropping the commit might be a nice solution. By leaving it as it is you mean merging the smile/dev branch into my branch? I just don’t think it’s clean to have two duplicate commits in tre tree, that does the same thing. Maybe my thinking is wrong?

Comment: “I just don’t think it’s clean to have two duplicate commits in tre tree” And I’m saying that’s a matter of opinion. In normal life this happens all the time due to things like cherry pick. So unless this causes trouble on a later merge, why not just leave it as it is? That’s just how your flow works, commits get copied.

Comment: @matt Thanks for your insights, I’m having trouble and confusions using rebase and trying to drop one of the commits, I’ll search a bit more. I found this interesting article that talks about the “cleanliness” related to doing a merge or a rebase: https://delicious-insights.com/en/posts/getting-solid-at-git-rebase-vs-merge/

Comment: Not mere rebase. Interactive rebase.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225940/discussion-between-gildev-and-matt).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your branch `sectronic` is not shared with many people (for example: if you are litterally the only one to use it, or perhaps you and a small team of devs, which you can easily contact), you may be ok with rewriting the history of your branch.

If such is the case, you can use rebase and force push your branch :

```
# from your 'sectronic' branch :
git checkout sectronic

# rebase on top of smile/dev :
git rebase smile/dev

# and force push :
git push --force-with-lease origin sectronic
```

If the branch is shared with other developers, you would have to tell them to update their local work too.

---

If the patches introduced by the two `F[io]x modem power on and off procedures` are 100% the same, `git rebase` will automatically identify the duplicate commit and remove it from your rewritten branch.

Comment: Thanks, that’s what I did (`git rebase sectronic smile/dev` to be precise which is the same if I’m not mistaken), and indeed my duplicate commit disappeared and my personnal commit got on top of the branch. This is indeed a branch I’m working on alone, so I guess I will be able to integrate future updates to the smile/dev branch into my sectronic branch in the same way.